# Compare Two Objects Properties and Obtain Missing Items

Tags: arrays, powershell, object

I'm attempting to compare two object properties called "name" and that contain the same type of data, in this case server host names. The objects are not identical AKA do not have the same properties. In short, I'm attempting to compare two lists of server names and determine where (which object) they are missing from.

I'm looking to find the items (server host names) that are missing from each object. When something is found I'm hoping to obtain all related properties for the item in the given object that it was found in. I can do the compare-object successfully, but don't know how to get the results I'm looking for.

I'm thinking two new objects could be created for each, that list the items that were not found in the other object maybe? Or do I somehow reference the previous objects with the output from compare-object and produce some formatted output?

This code currently produces a blank file.

**Data Format:**

$SNObject:

name,ip,class

server-place.com,10.10.10.10,windows server

$QRObject:

name,date,ip,general,device type

server-place1.com,11.11.11.11,random info,linux server

**Code Example:**

```
$compare = compare-object $SNObject $QRObject -property Name    | 

foreach  { 
  if ($_.sideindicator -eq '<=')
    {$_.sideindicator = $PathToQRReport }

  if ($_.sideindicator -eq '=>')
    {$_.sideindicator = $PathToSNReport}
 }

$compare | 
select @{l='Value';e={$_.InputObject}},@{l='File';e={$_.SideIndicator}} |
Out-File -FilePath C:\Temp\MissingOutputs1.txt
```

Comment: I believe what is happening is that in your foreach-object loop, you are attempting to assign a value to a property on an object that doesn't exist ($_.sideindicator) and also not emitting anything else to your $compare variable assignment which is why it's empty.  Check $compare after your loop to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh... just thought of an alternative that may give you exactly what you're looking for but in a slightly different way:

```
   ## Join both arrays into single array and then group it on the property name that has a shared value, 'name'
$all = @()
$group = @($SNObject + $QRObject)
$group | Group-Object -Property name | % {
    ## Create a custom object that contains all possible properties plus a directionality indicator ('source')
    $n = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        'name' = ''
        'date' = ''
        'ip' = ''
        'general' = ''
        'platform' = ''
        'source' = ''
    }

    if ($_.Count -eq 1) {
        ## Loop through the grouped results and determine their source and write properties based off of their source
        foreach ($i in $_.Group) {

            if (@($i | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | Select-Object -ExpandProperty name) -contains 'date' ) {
                ## This value came from $QRObject which apparently is the only dataset that contains a date property
                $n.source = 'QRObject'
                $n.date = $i.date
                $n.general = $i.general
                $n.platform = $i.'device type'
            } else {
                ## This object does not contain the 'date' property, therefore it came from $SNObject    
                $n.source = 'SNObject'
                $n.platform = $i.class
            }

            ## write out common properties
            $n.name = $i.name
            $n.ip = $i.ip

            ## add the custom PSObject back to a master array with all formatted properties
            $all += $n
        }
    }
}

$all | out-whereever-you-want
```

Comment: You'll have to forgive my ignorance. I've implemented what you suggested because I think it makes perfect sense. I used your edit to reference it as $group. Should I then sort unique based on the name property? If so, how do I tell which object it came from at that point?

Comment: I was kind of leaving that up to you since I'm not entirely sure what you want to achieve:  all objects in a single format with identical properties, all objects in a single container (e.g. array), all objects in a single format knowing what side each came from, etc.

Comment: I'm attempting to find unique items (based on the name property) and then tell where they originally existed (which object) and show which items were missing from the other object. With the results having all properties they originally had. The result may be in two new objects e.g. SNObject-Unique and QRObject-Unique, so I could easily reference the objects and their properties and produce a nice report in the end.

Comment: In short, I'm trying to compare two lists of server names (listed in the name properties) and figure out where they are missing from (which object).

Comment: Thank you for this and I think we almost got it. However, the output is showing me results that exist within both as well. e.g. It's saying it was found in the $QRObject and combining properties from both, which is nice, but I'm only trying to look for missing items from each.

Comment: Maybe a while name does not match instead of an if statement? I'll see if I can figure that out.

Comment: as long as there's only one hostname entry in each array, just skip if the count is greater htan 1:  if ($_.Group.Count -eq 1) { do the work }.  the logic behind providing everything was that if you exported to csv and sorted by hostname, you could tell which ones weren't in either side by them only having a single entry.  the ones in both would have a double entry.  see edit

Comment: also, if you only care about the singular results, you can actually remove the foreach loop and recode for single item targeting of $_.Group[0].propertyname but I'll leave that to you.  the loop should still work regardless.